# How create dialog box with DialogBoxIndirect function

Tags: winapi

I have code

```
     DLGITEMTEMPLATE* item1 = new DLGITEMTEMPLATE();
     item1->style = BS_PUSHBUTTON;
     item1->x = 10;
     item1->y = 10;
     item1->cx = 10;
     item1->cy = 10;
     item1->id = Modal_Button1;
     DLGTEMPLATE* dlgtmp =new DLGTEMPLATE();
     dlgtmp->cdit = 1;
     dlgtmp->style =  WS_SYSMENU;
     dlgtmp->x = 0;
     dlgtmp->y = 0;
     dlgtmp->cx = 100;
     dlgtmp->cy = 100;
     DialogBoxIndirect(((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, dlgtmp, hwnd, DlgProc);
```

---

```
    BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
   {
        switch (iMsg)
    {

    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

I have no idea how connect item1 to dlgtemp!

The error is thrown when I try use DialogBoxIndirect function.

```
Exception thrown at 0x004C302F in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00320005.
```

Comment: The Windows API doesn't throw exceptions. Please provide an error description that matches the reported error. Also show a [mcve].

Comment: Exception thrown at 0x004C302F in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00320005.

Comment: Please read the [DialogBoxIndirect() documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dialogboxindirectw), it explains exactly how to setup the DLGTEMPLATE and DLGITEMTEMPLATE together, and even provides a link to a full code example: [Creating a Template in Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes#creating-a-template-in-memory)

Comment: I have already tried that example but found that it doesnt work for me.
While I call that function I have almost the same error.Moreover Visual Studio says that 
`lpdt->style = WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_SYSMENU | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_CAPTION` deferencing NULL pointer lpdt

Comment: That example works and should tell you everything you need to know. Try it again.

Comment: The sample in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes) is also valid for me, maybe you can provide more code snippets and test environment so that we can find the problem.